# Sum over foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I'd appreciate if somebody could help me with this.
In postgres I have table that looks like this

```
id     | main_table_id | tax_id | value  | tax_value 
------ | ------------  | ------ | ------ | ------
1      | 1             | 1      | 10.00  | 1.00  
2      | 1             | 2      | 15.00  | 2.00  
3      | 1             | 1      | 17.00  | 3.00
```

Somehow, I need to sum columns 'value' and  'tax_value'  over tax_id and get result like this

```
| main_table_id | sum_value_1  | sum_value_2  | sum_tax_value_1  | sum_value_2  
| ------------  | ------ ------| ------------ | -----------------| -------
| 1             | 27.00        | 15.00        | 4.00             | 2.00
```

sum_value_1 is sum(value) for tax_id= 1,

sum_value_2 is sum(value) for tax_id= 2,

sum_tax_value_1 is sum(tax_value) for tax_id= 1,

sum_tax_value_2 is sum(tax_value) for tax_id= 2..

In table 'taxes' I have 10 different taxes, and tax_id is its FK.

Is it posible?

Comment: `I have 10 different taxes` ... and do you expect 10 columns for each tax?

Comment: I dont understand question? I have to sum value and value_tax in the way I tried to explain.

Answer (score 1):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select mt.main_table_id,
       sum(case when mt.tax_id = 1 then mt.value else 0 end) as sum_value_1,
       sum(case when mt.tax_id = 1 then mt.tax_value else 0 end) as sum_tax_value_1,
       sum(case when mt.tax_id = 2 then mt.value else 0 end) as sum_value_2,
       sum(case when mt.tax_id = 2 then mt.tax_value else 0 end) as sum_tax_value_2
from maintable mt
group by mt.main_table_id;
```

You can easily generalize this by adding more `sum( . . . )` expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(VALUE), SUM(TAX_VALUE) FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY TAX_ID;
```